# jQuery Concatenate multiple DOM node references into one list

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

Lets say for example I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="level0">
    <div>level 0 #1</div>
    <div class="contents">
        <div class="level1">
            <div>level 1 #1</div>
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="level2"><div>level 2 #1</div></div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="level0">
    <div>level 0 #2</div>
    <div class="contents">
        <div class="level1"><div>level 1 #2</div></div>
        <div class="level1"><div>level 1 #3</div></div>
        <div class="level1">
            <div>level 1 #4</div>
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="level2"><div>level 2 #2</div></div>
                <div class="level2"><div>level 2 #3</div></div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="level0"><div>level 0 #3</div></div>
```

I want to get all of the references to nodes with class "level0", "level1", or "level2".
Then **I want to iterate over them starting with the "level2" references, then going to "level1", then "level0".**

For instance, the following code would work for what I am trying to do:

```
$(".level2").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).children().first().text());
});
$(".level1").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).children().first().text());
});
$(".level0").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).children().first().text());
});
```

That would make the console output be the following:
**level 2 #1

level 2 #2

level 2 #3

level 1 #1

level 1 #2

level 1 #3

level 1 #4

level 0 #1

level 0 #2

level 0 #3**

As you can see, they are in order based on class, THEN by order in the HTML from top to bottom. **This is what I want**

However, I want to store this list of elements in this order **so I can just use one loop for all of the elements.**

The following code is similar to what I want but displays iterates through the rows in the wrong order.

```
var $rows = $(".level2, .level1, .level0");
$rows.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).children().first().text());
});
```

This iterates through the rows using in-order traversal.
Is there any way to append these rows into a single variable that I can iterate over in the order I wanted way above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled upon a working answer looking through a plugins source code.

The solution uses jQuery function `$.merge()`.

The following code accomplishes what I want to do:

```
var $rows = $(".level2");
var $rows = $.merge($rows,$(".level1"));
var $rows = $.merge($rows,$(".level0"));

$rows.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).children().first().text());
});
```

I supposed if you wanted to get a little more tricky, the following code would also work:

```
var $allRows = $.merge($.merge($(".level2"),$(".level1")),$(".level0"));

$allRows.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).children().first().text());
});
```

Check out **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YzbY/1/)** to see both options working.

Answer (score 1):

A rough example using a for loop and `_map`

```
var allArr = [],
    maxLevel = 2;
for (var i = maxLevel; i > -1; i--) {
    var arr = $('.level'+ i ).children('div:first-child').map(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text());
    }).get();
    allArr = allArr.concat(arr);    
}
console.log(allArr);
```

Needs to be refactored though.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sm8Ah/)**